# Using DIFFERENCE in a WHERE clause

Tags: t-sql

I want to use the `DIFFERENCE` keyword in a T-SQL query to find data that is equal or very similar between two data sets. `DIFFERENCE` returns a score from 1-4, where 4 is very similar and 1 is not similar at all.

For example, if I have two data sets, A and B, that contain the following:

```
A          B
----       ----
adam       adam
bob        billy
charlie    brittany
doug       charles
frances    diana
heather
kim
```

I would want to select ones that are equal or similar (say, `DIFFERENCE` value of 3 or 4), so I would want the result set (which stems from data set A) of:

```
Result
----
adam
charlie
```

My thought is to put the `DIFFERENCE` keyword in the `WHERE` clause, something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
/* somehow join B here, despite that A and B might not be exact matches such as in charlie and charles */
WHERE DIFFERENCE(A, B) >= 3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
from a 
join b
on difference(a.name, b.name) = 4;
```